# Efficient and cross platform way of loading images in Java

Tags: java, image, text, cross-platform, embedded-resource

I am learning to create game in Java and requires loading several images in before animating them. This is what I am doing now:

```
bg = new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/img/bg.jpg").getImage();
```

But clearly it has many disadvantages. For a start, it is long and ugly looking and I suspect, slow. <del>Additionally, the forward slashes "/" would only work on Mac or Linux, where as on windows, it would use back slashes.</del>

EDIT: As corrected by Samuel Rossille below, forward slash "/" in fact do work on windows.

I was wondering are there anyway of loading images, that are in the application directory, and won't be changed, in a more elegant fashion, as well as being cross-platform?

What about loading text files? Are they any different?

Comment: Plz note that forward slashes work on windows in java. You can open the file new File("C:/foo/bar.txt") for example, and even new File(""c:\\foo/bar.txt") if you really want it. You should consider removing the assertion about slashes from your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the info. on [embedded resources](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info).  Note that most methods & constructors that accept a `File` will also accept an `InputStream` or `URL`.  Embedded resources are read only.

---

On the matter of files (in the rare instance you might be using them and have to form the path from a `String`).

```
String fileSep = System.petProperty("file.separator");
bg = new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir")+
    fileSep+
    "src"+
    fileSep+
    "img"+
    fileSep+
    "bg.jpg").getImage();
```

This is one way to get a directory path that uses the correct separator for the file-system.  The `File` class also offers handy constructors like [`new File(parent,child)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) that will insert the correct separator.

As an aside, I strongly feel that all the methods & constructors in the J2SE that accept a `String` intended to represent a `File` path should be deprecated.  If it needs a `File`, give it a `File` and be done with it.

Comment: Also, you can use File.separatorChar to get the platform-specific file separator character instead of the "/" character. That way it will work on Mac, Linux and Windows.

Comment: @Ewald  Good point, I'd just been typing an update on the matter of `File` objects.

Comment: Phew! Was worried you were slacking :)  Great answer, +1 from me.